# How to hide scrollbar in Plotly Dash Table

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have table with a large number of rows, and I want to show everything inside my app.

By default, `dash_table.DataTable` adds a scrollbar when the table is too long. I would like to remove that scrollbar.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have the following application, where the height is set to 300px and overflow is automatic:

```py
import dash
import dash_table
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/1962_2006_walmart_store_openings.csv"
)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

table = dash_table.DataTable(
    id="table",
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
    data=df.to_dict("records"),
    style_table={"height": "300px", "overflowY": "auto"},
)

app.layout = html.Div([html.H1("Header"), table, html.Button("Click here")])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

You will get this resulting app:

[image]

In your case, you want to hide the scroll bar. You might be tempted to change the `style_table` to:

```py
style_table={"height": "300px", "overflowY": "show"}
```

Although the entire table will be shown, this unfortunately means the button will be hidden since the table is overflowing beyond the designated height:

[image]

So the correct change is to simply set the height of the table to be unlimited:

```py
style_table={"height": None}
```

And the button will show up correctly:

[image]

Controlling the height of the table is thoroughly documented in [Dash Table docs](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/height). It will show you different ways to use `overflowY`.

Answer (score 0):

add this argument into dash_table.DataTable:

```
virtualization=False
```

and you don't need to touch the height